# How do i get a list of json objects from json file

Tags: c#, json, xml

I could serialize one node of json file like below

```
using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{               
   deserializedJson = eerializer.Deserialize<Person>(jsonReader);
}
```

JsonNRadio is autogenerated class with json file.
Now my json file has multiple json objects.
so, for this i created a class called Persons

```
public class Persons
{
   private Person[] person;

   public Person[] person
   {
      get
      {
         return this.person;
      }
      set
      {
         this.person= value;
      }
   }
}

public partial class Person
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I should get a aaray of json objects but when I am trying with below code, I am getting only the first node.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"D:\\Sample.json"))
// deserializedXml = serialized.Deserialize(xmlStream);
using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
   Persons deserializedXml = serializer.Deserialize<Persons> (jsonReader);    
}
```

And Person is object is coming *null*.

Could anybody help with an example or how to get a list of json objects.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: {"id":"6397486515343190","name":"Henry"},{"id":"6397486515343192","name":"Paul"}

Comment: I should get an array of Persons object

Comment: Is the json file generated by you?

Comment: No, this is the format  of the file we get from some ftp location

Comment: you must have [ ] around the list of objects like this: [{prop1:value,prop2:value},{prop1:value,prop2:value}]

Answer (score 0):

For receiving json data with your *Persons* class above, your json file have to look like this:

```
{"Person":[{"id":"6397486515343190","name":"Henry"},{"id":"6397486515343192","name":"Paul"}]}
```

But since you have no influence on the design of the json data, you could simply deserialize it into a list of Person:

```
using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
   var deserializedXml = serializer.Deserialize<List<Person>> (jsonReader);    
}
```

This should work for you.

For editing your json string before deserialize it because of the missing "[" and "]". You can use something like that if you don't want to add much more new code:

```
using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
   var json = "[" + jsonReader.Value.ToString() + "]";    
   var deserializedXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
}
```

Or you can read the file with a normal *FileReader* into a string object and adding the "[", "]" at the beginning and ending.

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Person]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @Shruti is your JSON valid? http://jsonlint.com/ paste a sample JSON here to check. If it's not outputting a valid JSON, you might need to fix it when you get it.

Comment: I guess it's because the missing "[",  "]" at the beginning and the and of the json file. One option is to first read your file into a string object then adding a "[" at the beginning and a "]" at the end and after this deserialize the string like I showed above.